# How to disable collision between a link and a newly added collision object?

Tags: ros, moveit, planning-scene

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a scene with UR10 arm mounted on wall. I also have a table. I have this entire scene configured using moveit setup assistant.

I launch the scene. I then run a node(part_spawner) which spawns a mesh on the table(I am doing this by loading a mesh and adding this mesh as a collision object to planning_scene_interface). My rviz screen properly loads it and spawns it, as expected rviz also shows that there is a collision between the table and the mesh. But when I check for the collisions in the same node(part_spawner) using `planning_scene.CheckCollision(collision_request, collision_result, copied_state, allowed_collision_matrix)`, the collision_result does not return any contact between table and mesh. I'm guessing this should ideally return a pair of contact (table, mesh)

My goal is to manually disable this specific collision by adding the pair (table, mesh) to the Allowed Collision Matrix using `allowedCollisionMatrix.setEntry('table', 'mesh', true)`. But the collision is not being detected in the first place.

Is this the right way of doing it?

Is there a better way to do it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/367888/how-to-disable-collision-between-a-link-and-a-newly-added-collision-object?/) by [srujan](https://answers.ros.org/users/51644/srujan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 32 on 2020-12-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, you describe the correct way of disabling collision checking between two bodies.

But this post contains the unspoken question "Why are collisions not detected for my newly added collision object?", which needs to be answered: I suspect that the `PlanningScene` object that you are calling `checkCollision` on is not the same as the one that RViz displays, and that is why you are not seeing the collision. You can use a [PlanningSceneMonitor](https://ros-planning.github.io/moveit_tutorials/doc/planning_scene_monitor/planning_scene_monitor_tutorial.html) to get the newest scene, or use the `/get_planning_scene` service (this is probably easier). [Here is some boilerplate code](https://github.com/o2as/ur-o2as/blob/f8e704f4b598093697f6fa65389a88d1f941903d/catkin_ws/src/o2as_skills/src/o2as_skill_server.cpp#L922) for the latter, which you can copy from:

```
bool SkillServer::updatePlanningScene()
{
  moveit_msgs::GetPlanningScene srv;
  // Request only the collision matrix
  srv.request.components.components = moveit_msgs::PlanningSceneComponents::ALLOWED_COLLISION_MATRIX;
  get_planning_scene_client.call(srv);
  if (get_planning_scene_client.call(srv))
  {
    ROS_INFO("Got planning scene from move group.");
    planning_scene_ = srv.response.scene;
    return true;
  }
  else
  {
    ROS_ERROR("Failed to get planning scene from move group.");
    return false;
  }
}
```

Regarding a better way to enable/disable collisions: Internally I am using [this extension of the planning_scene_interface](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/pull/1440) that defines the functions `allowCollisions` and `disallowCollisions` and connects them to the Python interface as well, but we did not merge this upstream because the updating method is not strictly safe. If you are confident that it does not affect your application, you can use those changes as well.

Related question: https://answers.ros.org/question/359898/faster-way-to-disable-and-enable-collision-check-between-gripper-and-object/

---

Originally posted by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) with karma: 2180 on 2020-12-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [srujan](https://answers.ros.org/users/51644/srujan/) on 2020-12-18**:
Thanks for the answer @fvd . I used [this](https://answers.ros.org/question/352656/disabling-collision-in-allowedcollisionmatrix-removes-attached-object-from-the-scene/) post as a reference to get this working

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2020-12-18**:
Thanks for adding the reference. Don't forget to accept the answer to take the question out of the queue, too.